# How to load an html snippet into page without changing pages

Tags: php, html, templates, include

I'm new to PHP (3 days) and I understand the basic concept of using includes for creating high level templates. I'd like to further utilize this tool to load more granular content, but I'm not sure how to approach this. The html below is an example of a page template put together with php includes. If you reference this html, let's say I have a widget on the page contained here: `<?php include('include/WIDGET.php'); ?>`. In the simplest of scenarios, there would be a link above the widget that reads "Widget 2". On click of this link, I would want the `WIDGET.php` content to be replaced with `widget2.php`. How can I manipulate the include to load `widget2.php`?

***HTML***

```
<!-- File: index.php -->  

        <html>
            <head>
                <?php include('include/head.php');?>
                <title><?php echo $siteName;?></title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <?php include('include/header.php'); ?>
        <!-- CONTENT -->
                <?php include('include/WIDGET.php'); ?>
                <?php include('include/main-content.php'); ?>
        <!-- CONTENT END -->
                <?php include('include/footer.php'); ?>
            </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To change what file(s) is included, you would need to provide some sort of parameter to the page, that can conditionally include the correct widget.

For example, including it in URL query string, such as:

`http://yoursite/index.php?content=widget2`

**Then, in your PHP file, you can get this value:**

```
if (isset($_GET['content']) && !empty($_GET['content'])) {
     $widget = $_GET['content'];
} else {
     $widget = 'widget';
}
```

And include it in your HTML:

```
[...]
<!-- CONTENT -->
<?php include('include/' . $widget . '.php'); ?>
[...]
```

This is just to give you an example of the logic involved, but I wouldn't use the code as I've provided it as it is incredibly insecure, and doesn't check the existence of files, etc.

I know you're just getting started, and it's a lot to take in at once, but you might want to consider using a PHP framework such as Zend or Symfony, or CakePHP to take advantage of some routing and templating solutions that have already been set up for you.